# i want to return data inside a block by using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c

I have a function using AFJSONRequestOperation, and I wish to return the result only after success. Could you point me in the right direction? I'm still a bit clueless with blocks and AFNetworking specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you had posted your code

Using `__block` you can use variable inside block

```
__block NSString *msg;
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [hud hide:YES];
        NSLog(@"Success %@",  operation.responseString);
        NSDictionary *message = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",message);
        msg = message
        ALERT(@"Posted", message[@"message"]);
    }
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
                                          NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                      }];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: Its not going into block when calling the method after long time its going into success Block

Comment: I actually cant understand what do you want. The success is when the request gets completed. The purpose of the block is to make the code inside it run independent. Tell me your requirement clearly so that we could help. Like what do you want to display and when.

Comment: my intend is when we are calling API using AFNetworking i want to go success block immediately, i mean i want to send synchronize request.